# Unable to return struct value in c++

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

I have two text files and the `Load function` transfers the data from both text files to a single struct (`Employee emp[length]`) with a const length of 2001. This is because there are 2000 employee details in the text file.

After loading the data into struct, I wanted to search and display employee data using the Select function.

The user will be prompted to choose which employee attribute and keyword that is going to be used for searching. However, I realize that I cannot return a `struct(emp[i])` or a string value(`emp[i].empId`). It will prompt out an error saying

> access violation reading location 0x00D2C000

However, I am able to display the string value(`emp[i].empId`) using `cout`.

May I know why can I `cout` the string value but not return it?

Thank you for your help in advance and sorry for my poor English.

`const int length = 2001;`

```
struct Employee {
string empId;
string dOB;
string height;
string weight;
string yrOfWork;
string salary;
string allowance;
string name;
string country;
string designation;
string gender;
string lvlOfEdu;
};

Employee emp[length];

void Load();
Employee Select(int k, string s, int c);


int main() {
bool quit = false;
int option;

while (quit != true) { //loop the program unless 7 is chosen
    Load();

    cout << "1. Add" << endl; //
    cout << "2. Delete" << endl;
    cout << "3. Select" << endl;
    cout << "4. Advanced Search" << endl;
    cout << "5. Standard Deviation" << endl;
    cout << "6. Average" << endl;
    cout << "7. Quit" << endl;

    cout << "Please key in an option: ";
    cin >> option;
    system("cls"); //to refresh the screen

    switch (option) {
    case 3: {
        int search;
        string key;

        cout << "1.  Employee ID" << endl;
        cout << "2.  Date of Birth" << endl;
        cout << "3.  Height" << endl;
        cout << "4.  Weight" << endl;
        cout << "5.  Years of Working" << endl;
        cout << "6.  Basic Salary" << endl;
        cout << "7.  Allowance" << endl;
        cout << "8.  Employee Name" << endl;
        cout << "9.  Country" << endl;
        cout << "10. Designation" << endl;
        cout << "11. Gender" << endl;
        cout << "12. Level of Education" << endl;

        cout << "Select By: ";
        cin >> search;
        cout << "Enter keyword: ";
        cin >> key;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            cout << Select(search, key, i).empId;
        }

        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        break;
        }
    }
}
}

Employee Select(int s, string k, int c) {
int result;
int i = c;

switch(s) {
case 1:

    result = emp[i].empId.find(k);
    if (result >= 0) {
        return emp[i];
    }

    break;
}
}

void Load() {
ifstream inFigures;
inFigures.open("profiles_figures.txt");
ifstream inWords;
inWords.open("profiles_words.txt");

if (inFigures.is_open()) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!inFigures.eof()) {

        inFigures >> emp[i].empId;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].dOB;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].height;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].weight;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].yrOfWork;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].salary;
        inFigures.ignore();
        inFigures >> emp[i].allowance;
        inFigures.ignore();
        i++;
    }
}
//inFigures.close();

if (inWords.is_open()) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!inWords.eof()) {

        getline(inWords, emp[i].name);
        getline(inWords, emp[i].country);
        getline(inWords, emp[i].designation);
        inWords >> emp[i].gender;
        inWords.ignore();
        inWords >> emp[i].lvlOfEdu;
        inWords.ignore();
        i++;
    }
}
//inWords.close();
}
```

Comment: 1) Please provide the input you used. What, do you think, your `Select` function returns if `s != 1`, or `result < 0`? 2) Aditionally, the reasoning of "_with a const length of 2001. This is because there are 2000 employee details in the text file." doesn't make sense. If there are exactly 2000` employee records in a file, the array of `2000` would suffice. The reason for possible issues, you might face is the [`inWords.eof ()` you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) when reading the file.

Comment: You don't need an extra element for arrays. I think you're confusing "C string" arrays with arrays in general.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I think is, what do you return if `Select` doesn't find  anything? The function is supposed to return an employee. You could have a special `Employee` with a nonsensical `empId` (e.g. `-1`) to indicate this, and change

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    cout << Select(search, key, i).empId;
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Employee selected = Select(search, key, i);
    if (selected.empId != -1)
    {
        cout << Select(search, key, i).empId;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could alter the `Select` function so that it returns a pointer `Employee *` and then return  `nullptr` if  there is  no match. That is

```
Employee* Select(int s, string k, int c)
{
    int result;
    int i = c;   // why not just use c directly? Or change the argument to int i?

    switch(s)
    {
    case 1:

        result = emp[i].empId.find(k);
        if (result >= 0)
        {
             return &emp[i]; // note taking address, could also write emp + i
        }

        break;   // don't need this with no further cases
     }

     return nullptr; // reached if no match above
}
```

Followed later by

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Employee* selected = Select(search, key, i);
    if (selected != nullptr)
    {
        cout << Select(search, key, i)->empId;  // not pointer indirection
    }
}
```

Really you'd probably want to return a `const Employee const*`, but that's another topic.

Yet another option is having `Select` throw an exception if it doesn't find  anything, and placing the  call to `Select(search, key, i);` in a `try .. catch` block. I generally prefer not to use exceptions for control flow like this, but it is another method.

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the problem by using your first method. However, the process of searching takes quite some time which is around 2 minutes. Is it consider a normal time range for a program to loop through 2000 set of data?

Comment: No, that sounds extremely slow.

Comment: Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: Hi just an update here. Turns out that I had accidentally inserted the Load function inside my Select function. The problem is solved by just deleting the Load function from the Select function.